# Creating a custom webview from scratch

Tags: ios

I am in a situation where I want more flexibility for webview than the offered by UIWebview and not at all by WKWebview. Things like customizing web request before start eg sending headers and redirections. Also as we know UIWebview officially deprecated now in iOS 12.

I'm looking forward to a generic webview now, I know its possible as open source examples say Firefox for iOS.
If you've been using any of your projects or know please tell me. Or if you can give me some information how can this be achieved or any tutorails links would be helpful.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic, but using any web rendering engine other than an Apple-supplied one will get your app rejected from the App Store.  Read the Developer Agreement for more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info, so there is absolutely no way to build your own web view in iOS? Is this achievable with URLConnection?

Comment: It's *explicitly* disallowed by Apple.  It's why Chrome, etc. all use WKWebView or UIWebView.

Comment: Okay I'll raise a bounty for it and do some research, I might need to work on it as my side project.

Comment: @par do you have any source or links that prove this statement?

Comment: See Apple's [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements), specifically section 2.5.6.  I assure you you're not the first person to be deeply bothered by this policy.

Comment: Okay. thanks @par will try to see other ways to achieve following appstore guidelines :) Please post it as an answer and need votes to close.

Answer (score -1):

Declare the WebView object

```
var webView: WKWebView!
```

//Load the data in webView

```
func loadUrl() {

    var webView : WKWebView!
    let script: WKUserScript = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    let userContentController: WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.userContentController = userContentController
    userContentController.addUserScript(script)
    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.allowsLinkPreview = true

    //Load the Data from URL
    let url = URL(string: "Your URL")
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    urlRequest.setValue("user-agent", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

    webView.load(urlRequest)


    //Load the Data from local HTML

    do {
        guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Your-HTML-File", ofType: "html")
            else {
                print ("FILE READING ERROR")
                return
        }
        //get the content of HTML File
        let contents =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath , encoding: .utf8)
        webView.loadHTMLString(contents, baseURL:URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath))
    }
    catch {
        print ("FILE HTML ERROR")
    }
}
```

//Delegate Method that called when webView finish Loading.
//You can apply css or style here

```
 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {        
        ///Local CSS File
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Local-CSS-File", ofType: "css") else { return }
        let script = "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];var link = document.createElement('link');link.rel = 'stylesheet';link.type = 'text/css';link.href = '\(path)';link.media = 'all';head.appendChild(link);"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) {(result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        //External CSS File
        let externalCSSLink = "your-css-file-url"
        let script2 = "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];var link = document.createElement('link');link.rel = 'stylesheet';link.type = 'text/css';link.href = '\(externalCSSLink)';link.media = 'all';head.appendChild(link);"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString1) {(result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```